# Cannot set linked server in SQL Server 2008 with Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, linked-server

I want to link Oracle database with SQL server. I have used SQL Server's builtin LinkedServer SPs but it returned the following error.

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDAORA"
>   for linked server "OracleLinkedServer".

I have used the following commands in SQL Server Express 2008 to create a linked server.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   'OracleLinkedServer', 'Oracle',   'MSDAORA', 'OracleServer' 

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'OracleLinkedServer', false,  'sa', 'system',  '123456'

select * from OracleLinkedServer..system.CIL_NOTIFICATION
```

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution of this problem. The version of Oracle application, which I have installed, is 11gR1

My Oracle database was not started and mounted, so I used **startup** command

Then I have checked the listener of the database, It  should be started.

Then I have modified the statements mentioned in the question. Here is the modification.

```
--add a linked server into SQL server
--parameters: serverName, ServerProduct, ProviderName, DataSource / Listener Name of desired database
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   'OracleLinkedServer', 'Oracle',   'MSDAORA', 'PC-2.my.xgen/nb' 

--add login information into linked server
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'OracleLinkedServer', false,  Null, 'system',  '123456'

select * from OracleLinkedServer..SYSTEM.CIL_NOTIFICATION
```

It returns all the records from the Oracle database table CIL_NOTIFICATION